# JQuery - Get the ID attribute of li element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pagination control who's `<li>` elements are dynamically set and assigned a ID. Using jQuery I am then attempting ti retrieve these set ID's

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
   <ul class="pagination" id="pagHolder"></ul>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

    //*****Logic for setting 'mainArrayHolder'*****

    for(var i = 0; t < mainArrayHolder.length; i++)
    {
       $('#pagHolder').append('<li id="'+i+'"><a href="#">'+ i +'</a></li>');
    }
 });
</script>
```

**The Issue I have is** I am receiving an 'undefined' error when using the following function:

```
$(this).click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    alert(id);
});
```

I understand this is because 'this' is looking at the whole of the DOM rather than just the `<li>` elements. How do I set this code so it will get the id attribute of any of the `<li>` elements a user clicks?

Comment: All of the solutions except for the negative vote one should work for you.  However, in your example, you have a typo `for(var i = 0; t < mainArrayHolder.length; i++)` should be `for(var i = 0; i < mainArrayHolder.length; i++)`.  Notice your second parameter is `t` and not `i`.  Lastly, here is a working fiddle with one of the solutions below: https://jsfiddle.net/fpvedn3w/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the selector for your `click` event.

The following should work:

```
$('#pagHolder').on('click', 'li', function() {  
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Notice that we use the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, and delegate the event to any `li` which exists now (or in the future) as a child node of `pagHolder`.

Alternatively, you don't need to use jQuery's `attr()` function inside of the event handler, since `this` relates to the DOM node itself, you can access its properties directly, for example:

```
$('#pagHolder').on('click', 'li', function() {  
    alert( this.id );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are appending `li`'s to `#pagHolder` list, so you could get ids like this, for example:

```
$('#pagHolder').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```